# Apache and PHP causing timeout in server

Tags: php, apache, apache2, timeout

If i use the code in one script, like:

```
ignore_user_abort(1);
sleep(30);
```

And i close the page, the client stay in a timeout for 30 seconds to any page of server. I try put "Timeout 5" in the apache2.conf to close the connection of client but nothing...

- I enter in the page: www.example.com/timeout.php ( using the code sleep(30) )
- Close the page
- Enter in the page: www.example.com/somebody.php ( the content just a "Hello, World" )
- Stay loading the page... and for 30 seconds the page load.

Somebody can help?
Thank.

Comment: Did you restart the Apache server after making changes to the config file? You probably did, but you never know...

Comment: What do you mean with "Close the page" ?

Comment: Could it be you limited the http server to only a single worker process? So that all requests are processed one after another?

Comment: Are you using sessions? session files are locked by the first script doing a session_start() and are not released until the script exits. try adding a `session_write_close()` to your sleep() script.

Comment: The problem has the session, i put the function "session_write_close()" in the script and now its ok. Thank you Marc B.